# boofuzz / process_monitor.py - pdx: [50] DebugActiveProcess(X): The request is not supported

Tags: python, fuzzing

I asked a question recently that received an answer that fixed my then-problem, viewable [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722029/boofuzz-ped-rpc-remote-method-restart-target-cannot-be-found), for my boofuzz counterparts.  Unfortunately, I'm now receiving another error: `pdx: [50] DebugActiveProcess(X): The request is not supported.` (note, `X` value is the PID value, which changes as noted in output) now that the previous bug has been addressed.  I am running Python 2.7.9 on a 64-bit Windows 7, Service Pack 1 machine.

Here're relevant parts of my boofuzz script:

```
def fuzz(dst, dport):
    # Create session, specify high-arbitrary crash_threshold, low restart_sleep_time, check_data_received_each_request=False
    session = sessions.Session(
        crash_threshold="10000", 
        check_data_received_each_request=0,
        restart_sleep_time=0.1, 
        sleep_time=0.1,
    )
    # Define target
    target = sessions.Target(
        connection = SocketConnection(dst, dport, proto='tcp')
    )
    # Define procmon options
    target.procmon = pedrpc.Client(dst, 26002)
    target.procmon_options = {
        "proc_name" : "disksvs.exe",
        "stop_commands" : ['net stop "Disk Savvy Enterprise"'],
        "start_commands" : ['net start "Disk Savvy Enterprise"']        
    }
```

I get an error on my procmon machine, after connecting.  Here's the output, as run:

**Fuzzing machine:**

```
root@kali:~/scripts/exploits/diskSaavy# ./boofuzz-diskSaavy.py 192.168.138.142 9124
[2018-04-12 18:41:16,385]     Info: current fuzz path:  -> packet
[2018-04-12 18:41:16,385] Test Case: 1
[2018-04-12 18:41:16,385]     Info: primitive name: "SC 1", type: String, default value: SERVER_GET_INFO
[2018-04-12 18:41:16,385]     Info: Test case 1 of 6380 for this node. 1 of 6380 overall.
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,456]   Test Step: Fuzzing Node 'packet'
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,456]     Transmitting 37 bytes: 75 19 ba ab 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 1a 00 00 cc 20 00 00 00 02 32 01 44 41 54 41 01 30 01 00 00 00 60 c0 f1 02 b'u\x19\xba\xab\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x00\xcc \x00\x00\x00\x022\x01DATA\x010\x01\x00\x00\x00`\xc0\xf1\x02'
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,456]     Info: 37 bytes sent
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,456]   Test Step: Calling post_send function:
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,456]     Info: No post_send callback registered.
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,456]   Test Step: Sleep between tests.
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,457]     Info: sleeping for 0.100000 seconds
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,557]   Test Step: Contact process monitor
[2018-04-12 18:41:23,557]     Check: procmon.post_send()
^C[2018-04-12 18:41:23,696]     Error!!!! SIGINT received ... exiting
```

**Procmon Machine:**

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\boofuzz>python process_monitor.py
Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
[06:31.24] Process Monitor PED-RPC server initialized:
[06:31.24]       crash file:  C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\boofuzz\crash-bin
[06:31.24]       # records:   0
[06:31.24]       proc name:   None
[06:31.24]       log level:   1
[06:31.24] awaiting requests...
[06:31.56] updating target process name to 'disksvs.exe'
[06:31.56] updating stop commands to: ['net stop "Disk Savvy Enterprise"']
[06:31.57] updating start commands to: ['net start "Disk Savvy Enterprise"']
[06:31.57] starting target process
[06:31.57] done. target up and running, giving it 5 seconds to settle in.
The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.

[06:32.02] debugger thread-1523572322 attaching to pid: 3436
Exception in thread 1523572322:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "process_monitor.py", line 100, in run
    self.dbg.attach(self.pid)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydbg\pydbg.py", line 226, in attach
    self.debug_active_process(pid)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydbg\pydbg.py", line 839, in debug_active_process
    raise pdx("DebugActiveProcess(%d)" % pid, True)
pdx: [50] DebugActiveProcess(3436): The request is not supported.


[06:32.04] starting target process
[06:32.04] done. target up and running, giving it 5 seconds to settle in.
The requested service has already been started.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2182.

[06:32.09] debugger thread-1523572329 attaching to pid: 1460
Exception in thread 1523572329:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "process_monitor.py", line 100, in run
    self.dbg.attach(self.pid)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydbg\pydbg.py", line 226, in attach
    self.debug_active_process(pid)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pydbg\pydbg.py", line 839, in debug_active_process
    raise pdx("DebugActiveProcess(%d)" % pid, True)
pdx: [50] DebugActiveProcess(1460): The request is not supported.
```

So to me, it looks as though I'm connecting properly and procmon receives my start, stop commands, and process name (all of which are accurate).  What's interesting however, is that the process doesn't appear to be restarted, but the PID changes with each iteration (in procmon).  This is obviously causing issues, as the PID of disksvs.exe does not match what procmon is attempting to attach to.  I'm kinda at a loss, as I've looked at the source files, but can't see exactly why procmon is grabbing an incorrect PID.

Procmon starts the service correctly if it is not started when fuzzing starts, which is great, but doesn't get far past.  I've also tried removing the `proc_name` parameter just to see what would happen, but no luck-- same error.

I'd be more than happy to provide more information, just let me know what you need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are trying to run a 32-bit application. I get the same error if process_monitor.py tries to attach to a 64-bit process. It looks like your target has both 32- and 64-bit options available.

The 32-bit checklist is:

1. The Python install with which you run the procmon should be 32-bits.
2. Procmon can only attach to a 32-bit process.

If the target application is 64-bit and it dies prematurely, I see "Access is denied." rather than "The request is not supported."

I created [this pull request](https://github.com/jtpereyda/boofuzz/pull/184) to improve the error handling and messages.

Comment: Hi jt, it's a 64-bit machine, but I'm running 32-bit python, and I believe the app is 32-bit as well.  I'm gonna step back and get it working with a standalone process, rather than  a service, and report back.  It's possible I just have some sort of configuration issue, I suppose.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @plast1K Did you figure out the solution?